# How can the question about an English grammar course be improved?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question [For a English Grammar Course, what should be included in the list below and what should be removed?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/4832/800) was closed because, according to the three close voters, it "needs to be more focused". The question lists a long number of topics that would need to be covered in an envisioned English grammar course. It also describes the audience for this course: L2 learners in lower-upper secondary school who will be taking exams that focus a lot on grammar.

The close voters did not provide any *specific* reasons for their close votes, nor advice on how the question could be improved. Questions on teaching grammar are on topic on this site and I don't see how this question could be split up into smaller ones in a *meaningful* way, since the question is about a syllabus as a whole.

For these reasons, I am asking how the question can be improved. If not, I would like to see a justification for the close votes that is more meaningful than "lacking focus".

Answer (score 2):

I am by no means an English teacher, though I do have teacher training on a different subject.

Some things that might help:

1. The course is aimed for some specific exams and presumably in a specific country or region. Naming this would give context to those who know about such matters. Is the course aimed for passing the exams (and maybe learning a bit of the language) or learning the language and thereby passing the exams, too?
2. Is there a lack of time when compared to content, as usual when teaching my field? How deeply is one intending to teach the content? For example, prepositions use could easily be added into example sentences that illustrate another point by adding a few words into an example sentence. Or one could have lessons devoted to practicing them.
3. A more abstract question about how to select grammar content for such a course might also be fruitful.